# what are the safety movements/measures when using forearms to attack?

Tags: kung-fu, safety, wing-chun, hung-gar

as the title, i want to know the safety movements in using the forearms to attack, especially the one with the forearms weapon like in hung gar, i am not knowledgeable in unarmed fighting but i believe it risky in damaging the wrist or the forearms if not done right, or maybe correct me if i am mistaken, and if theres any difference in using pure metal bracelet (not the ring one, i remember the original or historical one is made from bronze with spike) rather than leather?

here some forearms weapon example i can found.

from: https://www.webmartial.com/en/martial-arts/wing-chun-jeet-kune-do/wing-chun-rings/metal-bracelet-nan-quan-hong-jia-quan-tie-xian-quan-3-sizes.html

[image]

from:https://www.dragonsports.eu/en/11760-nan-quan-wrist-2.html

[image]

feel free to correct my grammar and the tag to be appropriate.